# how to set file upload path that works both on dev server and production server

Tags: php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/deslog/deslog/img/staffattachment/";???

here is the output on localhost: localhost/deslog/deslog/img/staffattachment/someimage.jpg.
this works well on local dev server but fails on production server
how do i fix this please? i need help.

here is the partial code block:
$image = (object) array('cv_data' => $file_name, 'description' => $description,
        'user_id' => $user_id);

```
$db = new DbHandler();
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/deslog/deslog/img/staffattachment/";

$isattachmentExists = $db->getOneRecord("select 1 from ".$table_name." where description='$description'");

    if (!$isattachmentExists) {

        $result = $db->insertIntoTable($image, $column_names, $table_name);
        if ($result != NULL) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path .$file_name);
```